# fail2ban cannot block ip public, it works only for private ip

Tags: iptables, apache2, fail2ban

My server live behind the reverse proxy nginx, but the ip of the client access shows in the apache log like this, looks normal, there is no x-forward things in the log.

```
103.221.234.206 - - [28/Feb/2024:14:37:29 +0800] "GET /styles/pke/?mejiku=zeus138 HTTP/1.1" 404 3888 "https://x.y.z.a/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.68"
65.109.34.52 - - [28/Feb/2024:14:37:29 +0800] "GET /index.php/index/user/register HTTP/1.1" 200 9568 "https://x.y.z.a/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.7.0 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
103.221.234.206 - - [28/Feb/2024:14:37:31 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8561 "https://x.y.z.a" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.68"
194.32.229.95 - - [28/Feb/2024:14:37:32 +0800] "GET /index.php/index/user/register HTTP/1.1" 200 9487 "https://x.y.z.a/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.7.0 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

Next.. the config fail2ban is good but iptables cannot block ip from the ip public. my iptables shown bellow. It only works when ban local ip.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 22909 packets, 8800K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 691K   72M f2b-apache-noscript  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
 690K   85M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   76  4560 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    1    60 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    1    64 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.0/8           anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
  807 42768 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.0/8           anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
34019 2040K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 720K packets, 2306M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     77.111.244.49        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     103.151.140.101      anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     20.125.101.243       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

My iptables can not catch up the traffic from that specific ip blocked.

What should I do to make my fail2ban works without changing the network topology where my server is behind the reverse proxy.

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP9Qd.png)

Comment: You haven't described your network topology.

Comment: [Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP9Qd.png), I only have full access in the webserver where the fail2ban installed and no access to configure the reverse proxy.

Comment: If you have a reverse proxy then the packets originate from the reverse proxy. That proxy adds a header telling who *originally* sent the packet, which your web server use. `iptables` however doesn't inspect HTTP headers, and doesn't match. You have to re-think your approach.

Comment: what would you suggest if the topology cannot change?? should used another apps?

Comment: update... I just found similar case here, and it perferctly solved: https://vaarlion.com/blog/how-to-use-fail2ban-when-there-is-a-proxy-in-the-way/

Comment: ServerFault is a not a forum and changing the question to include `solved` or similar statements is not how things are done. Please post an answer and accept that. In that answer include that link and preferably a short summary in case that link dies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar case and perferctly solved here: [link](https://vaarlion.com/blog/how-to-use-fail2ban-when-there-is-a-proxy-in-the-way/)

Comment: Please include the gist of the solution into your answer. The answer becomes useless when that link dies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).